# Let $g(z)=az^n-e^z$ with $|a| > e^1$. Show that $g$ must have $n$ different zeros on the circle with centre $0$ and radius $1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g(z)=az^n-e^z$ with $|a| > e^1$.

How do I show that $g$ must have $n$ different zeros on the circle with centre $0$ and radius $1$ ?

I've tried a solution by trial and error.

Comment: I think you must mean inside.

Comment: The standard way is Rouché's theorem, plus an argument that all zeros are simple.

Comment: How do I see that the zeros are simple ? This is the part that bothers me.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen See the answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean inside then let $f(z)=az^n$. Then $$|g(z)-f(z)|=|e^z|$$ On $|z|=1$, $$|e^z|=e^x \le e^1 \lt |a|$$
Thus On $|z|=1$ we have $$|g(z)-f(z)| \lt |f(z)|$$. By Rouche's theorem $f$ and $g$ have the same no of roots inside $|z| \lt 1$. Also all the zeroes are simple. Suppose that $z_0$ is a root and it is not simple. Then $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=0$. This would give that $$az_{0}^n=naz_{0}^{n-1}$$ which gives that $z_{0}=0$ which is not possible. Hence $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: How do I see that they are simple ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen See the answer now